# Visual studio 2015 mixed C#/C++ debugger extremely slow to start

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have a mixed managed/native desktop solution. When starting to debug it takes around a minute (!) to start, and breaks into the debuggee immediately.

Several more bits of info:

1) Breaks 'immediately' = breaks at this stack on the main thread:

```
>   kernel32.dll!GetFullPathNameW() Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!00007ffaa4f51310()  Unknown
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.IO.PathHelper.GetFullPathName() Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(string path = "D:\\cwx_tfs\\718_High_risk_branch\\Application\\Bin\\Debug\\CathWorksUI.exe.Config", bool fullCheck, int maxPathLength = 260, bool expandShortPaths = true)    Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(string path)    Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomainSetup.NormalizePath(string path, bool useAppBase)  Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomainSetup.VerifyDir(string dir, bool normalize)    Unknown
    System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.ClientConfigPaths(string exePath = null, bool includeUserConfig)    Unknown
    System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(string exePath, bool includeUserConfig = false)    Unknown
    System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(string configPath)  Unknown
    System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.IsAppConfigHttp.get() Unknown
    System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.ClientConfigurationSystem() Unknown
    System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()  Unknown
    System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()    Unknown
    System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(string sectionName = "system.diagnostics")    Unknown
    System.dll!System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(string sectionName)   Unknown
    System.dll!System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize() Unknown
    System.dll!System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Sources.get()    Unknown
    System.dll!System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize()  Unknown
    System.dll!System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Switch.get()  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.CreateTraceSource(string sourceName)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.DependencyPropertySource.get()  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.AvTrace.Initialize()    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.TraceDependencyProperty.TraceDependencyProperty()   Unknown
    ...
```

2) I see a thread that I'm not familiar with, starting at `ntdll.dll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin()`  which at the break is located at `ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart`.

3) There's a ~60s high CPU activity in the spawned process msvsmon ('Visual studio 2015 remote debugger').  When inspecting with WPA I see that a disproportional amount of time is spent at mscordbi.dll!ShimStackWalk. Specifically at this stack:

[image]

I do nothing fancy, just regular desktop debugging. I reproduced this in /safemode too, so it probably isn't an extension issue. This doesn't happen on other computers debugging the same code, so it isn't some exotic code issue. This persists after a VS re-install. Is it possible that somehow I'm using a non-default debugging engine?  Any other ideas would be very welcome.

---

Edit:

4) Just discovered that if I uncheck 'Enable native code debugging' the 60s delay is gone.   It is something specific to the mixed debugging engine.

---

Edit:

5) Just saw this in the VS ActivityLog.xml:

```
  <entry>
    <record>126</record>
    <time>2016/07/13 12:24:32.728</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
    <description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;DebuggerPackage.dll&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\DEBUGGING TOOLS FOR WINDOWS\DEBUGGERPACKAGE\DebuggerPackage.dll</path>
  </entry>
```

Sounds relevant. How can I fix it?

---

Edit:
I reported this [@Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2926615/debugging-wpf-application-with-certain-settings-takes-exceptionally-long-time-to-start-and-breaks-upon-entering).   If anyone is interested that might be a good place to follow. Please vote the issue if you're experiencing it too.

Comment: If you start without debugging and then attach, is the debug experience still slow? Or is it really just the startup/first break?

Comment: Also, what's in the Debug output pane in VS? That might give a clue why it's breaking there.

Comment: @Cameron starting without debugging is immediate. Attaching is very fast as well.

Comment: @Cameron the debug pane shows nothing but vanilla module load and symbols load messages.  Exception and thread/process messages are enabled.

Comment: Just discovered: unchecking 'Enable native code debugging' makes the delay go away.  The issue is limited to the mixed debug engine

Comment: Curious. It shouldn't be breaking in `GetFullPathNameW`. Without 'native code debugging', I imagine it doesn't break there, and thus doesn't spend a minute unwinding the stack.

Comment: If you enable either (or both?) 'Use Managed/Native Compatibility Mode' in the debugging options, does this affect anything?

Comment: @Cameron Thanks!  that indeed cut the delay by ~90%.   (do you understand how? I don't.. )    Please write this as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: I believe enabling those options causes alternate (legacy) debugger engines to be used, which obviously is not ideal. More of a workaround than a fix, really, so I won't submit that as an answer :-)

Comment: The "breaks immediately" observation ought to be a lead of sorts.  Be sure to start your program with F5 and not F10 or F11.  And in a mixed-mode program it is very important to enable the legacy debug engine, the default one in VS2015 cannot handle C++/CLI code anymore.  Tools > Options > Debugging > General > tick the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox.

Comment: @HansPassant  I start with F5 alright.  I used mixed-mode with the default debugger extensively, I *think* with C++/CLI as well. Is it official it isn't supported?    BTW I'm able to reproduce the problem on toy WPF application with all symbols loading and native debugging enabled. I'll find the time some day to report a connect bug.

Comment: This problem just started on one of my development machines too, and I'm not sure what triggered it because I've been running the same environment for a while now. Windows Updates are a possible culprit in my case. Does not happen in VS2013 and does not happen in VS2015 on another of my machines. Same two workarounds work for me (the Managed/Native Compatibility Mode settings and disabling native code debugging for the project) though only for former is a workable option for the debugging I need to do.

Comment: For me the issue went away after switching the startup object to a manually defined Main() method, even through it contains exacly the same code as generated for App.Main (in App.g.cs).

Comment: Changing the `C# Project Properties>Build>Platform target` from `x64` to `x86` works around the problem for me

Comment: This is still unfixed in Visual Studio 2019 ver. 16.10.2.